# Amavasya Kali Puja

Tags: devi, shakti, shaktism, kali

Another question from beginner level here, if anyone might have info :

Ok, so I knew some people a while back who kept Kali puja & vrat every Amavasya. So like twelve-thirteen times a year, I think.

Is this a thing in scriptures ?

They were Chinnamasta devotees, actually, if I recall correctly.

I'd only heard of Amavasya vrat for ancestors prior to that. When trying to look this up online, the ancestors version is coming up as well as the once-a-year Kali puja that happens on Diwali in NE India.

But apparently some devi-bhakts hold a small Kali-puja (and vrat) once every month on Amavasya ?